# height not working inside self invoking function

Tags: javascript, jquery

height not working inside self invoking function but it is ok inside(document).ready(function()

```js
(function($){
 var clientHeight = document.getElementById('home').clientHeight;
 alert(clientHeight);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<div id="home" style="background-position: 50% 0px; height: 635px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Is `jQuery` included ?

Comment: `$(function() { ... }) <==> $(document).ready(function() { ... }) !== (function($) { ... })(jQuery)`. Try: `(function($) { $(function() { ... }); })(jQuery)`

Comment: yes jQuery included! other functions are ok only height not working

Answer (score 0):

> Include `jQuery` library in your page or else you will find `jQuery is not defined` error in your console.

Try this:

```js
(function($) {
  var clientHeight = document.getElementById('home').clientHeight;
  alert(clientHeight);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home" style="background-position: 50% 0px; height: 635px;">
</div>
```

*Or just remove `document.ready`* as you are not using any other `jQuery` method

```js
(function() {
  var clientHeight = document.getElementById('home').clientHeight;
  alert(clientHeight);
})();
```

```html
<div id="home" style="background-position: 50% 0px; height: 635px;">
</div>
```

Comment: `(function($)` is not a shorthand for document.ready `$(function()` is , and I believe that the whole point of the question was getting the code to execute in the iffy

Comment: meaning that you are probably correct guessing that jQuery wasn't included , but not in the sense that he should remove the self-invoking function because the purpose of it here is not a shorthand for `document.ready` the purpose was to have self contained code section

Comment: What is the purpose of having `jQuery` as argument in IIFE then ?

Comment: I'm guessing that it is copied code from somewhere , and the purpose the way it is written is to inject jquery to the `$` for the specific code block , the reson for that may be because there are other libraries in the overall project that also are using `$`

Comment: jQuery included! other functions are ok only height not working